# adding Markdown syntax to a table in Hugo

Tags: hugo

Is it possible to add markdown synatx to a column in table in hugo?
I tried to use this table striped, but seems like it doesn't work.
here is an example of what I tried:

````
    {{<table "table table-striped table-responsive">}}
       | Operation  | URL    | Response
       | :----------|:------|:--------|                            
       | GET | `someURL` | response status code: 200
       ```json
       {
          "someJson": [
             {
             }
          ]
       }
       ```
      |
````

{{</table>}}